# Capture Triggered Send information in email ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

Is there any way for me to grab the triggered send definition name (e.g. the one that has a value similar to: **Email Activity name - 7f9946832b514c949f527fb484def80c**) via AMPScript in an email? I want to push it to a DE to help match it to an individual email result in SF.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can access the email name with this personalization string `%%emailname_%%`

Accessing it via AMPScript like:

```
%%[
  VAR @emailname
  SET @emailname = AttributeValue("emailname_")
%%]
```

Comment: Hey Travis, probably should have clarified, I'm looking to get the triggered send definition's name. Will edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: Hmm ok, I think an option then might be to log the %%jobid%% and then setup a query activity to join the triggered send name from the _Job data view to your DE. Would be interested to know if there is an even better way though.